# How to apply QueryDSL numeric mappings via ANT Task?

Tags: java, querydsl

I need to refine the default QueryDSL numeric type mappings. Therefore the Maven plugin provides the option

```
<numericMappings>
  <numericMapping>
    <size>1</size>
    <digits>0</digits>
    <javaType>java.lang.Integer</javaType>
  </numericMapping>
</numericMappings>
```

I haven't found a way to apply those mappings via the Ant task.

How can I apply numeric mappings via Ant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numeric mappings are currently not supported for Ant, but feel free to create a ticket for it.